# htaccess rules before wordpress own rules

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to add some rewrite rules to a Wordpress site, to go a little further than wp's own rewrite capabilities, but i am having trouble when I place those rules BEFORE wordpress own rules: if my rule rewrites to something that wordpress will rewrite later, it doesn't work. E.g:

www.domain.com/hello -> www.domain.com/image.jpg : this works, as wordpress doesn't interfere
www.domain.com/hello -> www.domain.com/category/1 : doesn't work, even if www.domain.com/category/1 works by itself

I've tried to remove the L tag from my rewrite rules, to allow further rewriting, but it doesn't seem to work...maybe wordpress does starnge things with htaccess?

Does this sound familiar to anyone?

Thank you

Comment: To allow people to better help you, post an example rule, example input, expected output, and current output.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress doesn't check the rewritten url (`/category/1`), but parses the original request url (`/hello`), and so it doesn't know what to do with `/hello`. To fix this use the proxy flag. So `[L]` would become `[L,P]`